# How can I create an Android AVD for a Samsung Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

I want to create an AVD to test apps on a Samsung Galaxy Note 2.
I have checked similar questions, but they are intended for older AVD versions.

Which device should I use?

Should I set the target as "Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10"?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know the following:

- Screen Size 5.55"
- Resolution 720w x 1280h
- Density xhdpi
- RAM 2 GiB
- Hardware buttons*

The rest I just left at the defaults:

- Sensors: Accelerometer, GPS, Gyroscope, Proximity Sensor
- Cameras: Front, Rear
- Input: No Nav
- Size: Large
- Screen Ratio: long
- Buttons: Software
- Portrait: Enabled
- Device States: Enabled

*Picture does not show the "Buttons" as hardware, but it should be.

[image: Here's a picture for you.]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Note 2 has a physical home button and two softkeys. I think that the software button setting will give you a graphical button bar across the bottom that only appears on devices without physical buttons.

Comment: Where is the dialog window you showed?  In Eclipse Virtual Devices Manager selecting new show a different window with built in devices definitions.

Answer (score 2):

This link will definitely help you with galaxy note 3 smart phone emulator.

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator

download file from this link and follow simple steps.

Hope this helps someone.....

Comment: Any idea where Samsung hides their repository.xml file?  Google does not include a url with the default SDK for "Samsung Electronics add-ons".

Comment: That link is for the old Galaxy Tab, not the same.

Comment: Go up a directory and you can search all the devices. However, you need an account at Samsung to download :-( I'm just creating my own with similar specs as the phone I have and am using default skin for now.

Answer (score 0):

> Which device should I use?

Unless Samsung has some downloadable device definitions that you can use, you should define your own device that matches the Note II as closely as you can.

> Should I set the target as "Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10"?

Only if for some reason you downgraded your Note II to Android 2.3.3. The Note II ships with Android 4.1 AFAIK.

Comment: Where can I download the device definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post one more answer, though others are good enough.

Some times emulator doesn't work as expected when we are looking for emulator which compatible with the real device. I faced may frustrating problem like this, after some exploration I found that Samsung provides a significant solution for this i.e RTL (Remote Test Lab) it is free.

For more information and how to use it check out Samsung [RTL Solution](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action)

Hope this one help you.