# Galaxy Note II emulator

Tags: android-virtual-device, basic4android

I am creating a emulator with options 720 X 1280 px, 5.5 inch size.

When I try my code on my real phone (a Galaxy Note II) the views are correct but when I use the emulator the view is just 2/3 of the screen. As we can say that the real phone shows the correct view, where is the problem with the emulator?

The real Note II has scale value 2 when I connect to it, but when I connect it to emulator it says scale value of 1.5, maybe the problem is this. How can I set the correct scale for the Note II phone in AVD or what am I doing wrong in AVD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a AVD for samsung galaxy note 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138863/how-can-i-create-a-avd-for-samsung-galaxy-note-2)

Answer (score -1):

The scale is very important. See this tutorial: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/17647/#content

You should set the DPI value to 320 (2 * 160).